# Sensitivity analysis for different coefficients in linear program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider a standard linear programming problem:

$$ \max \ c^{\top} x \\
~~~~~~~~\text{subject to } Ax = b, x \geq 0
$$

There is existing literature on how the optimal value of this linear program changes as the value of $b$ changes. Under certain conditions, the subgradient of the optimal value as a function $b$ can be related to the optimal dual variable.

However, is there a similar sensitivity analysis of the optimal value with respect to the vector $c$? For a small change in value of $c$, I would not expect the optimal value of the problem to change much but I cannot find a way to characterize this difference.

Any leads or references will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like an application of a version of the 'envelope theorem' for constrained maximization.

Comment: Thanks for the lead! That seems to be relevant. I'll try that out and see how it works out in my problem.